# Is it okay to be undecided in b/w industry or research in one's SOP for grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, statement-of-purpose

I am a little unsure about whether I will end up doing research or being in the industry, after my masters. A good part of me wants to be in academia and I really liked the little research projects I took up during my undergrad.
Is it okay to be unsure and say that I want to explore a little more before I settle with the right choice in the SOP?